# flume configuration - spoolDir and file roll sink's variable

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I've searched and there are multiple posts about how to use the `'fileHeader'` and `'basenameHeader'` for `spoolDirectory`, though it seems not to work in my case.

My goal is to use Flume to ingest file(s) from a local directory into a blob directory using `file_roll` sink and to retain the file name or at least put the file in a directory that has the same name as the file name.
For example,

> /input/january.txt **->** /blob_output/january.[timestamp] or /input/january.txt  **->** /blob_output/january/[timestamp].txt

The problem is I can't seem to call the variable of the filename or basename as it always returns nothing (or null) resulting in only a timestamp in the output name.
Here's my flume configuration:

```
training_agent.sources = src1
training_agent.channels = ch1
training_agent.sinks = sink1

training_agent.sources = src1
training_agent.channels = ch1
training_agent.sinks = sink1

training_agent.sources.src1.type = spooldir
training_agent.sources.src1.channels = ch1
training_agent.sources.src1.spoolDir = /home/training/input/
training_agent.sources.src1.batchSize = 5
training_agent.sources.src1.fileHeader = true

training_agent.channels.ch1.type = memory
training_agent.channels.capacity = 500
training_agent.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity = 50

training_agent.sinks.sink1.type = file_roll
training_agent.sinks.sink1.sink.rollInterval = 0
training_agent.sinks.sink1.channel = ch1
training_agent.sinks.sink1.sink.directory = /blobtraining_path/destination
training_agent.sinks.sink1.sink.pathManager.prefix = ${file}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink) of Rolling File Sink, there is no option to specify filename of the output file.

I check the [source](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/RollingFileSink.java) to find a way to solve this problem but there is no simple way to do it. Flume use only current timestamp to generate a filename. You can only specify prefix and extension for the output file.

However, you can extend the `DefaultPathManager` and add an ability for do this or you can create a new custom sink (your own rolling file sink) which has the ability of getting filename header from the flume event headers and use this information to create output file with the same value of the input file.

To creating a custom sink, you can take a look at [Flume Developer Guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink)'s Sink section.

*Extra information:*

```
training_agent.sinks.sink1.sink.pathManager.prefix = ${file}
```

You can not directly use an environment variable in flume configuration files. If you want to use an environment variable in your flume configuration you have to add this to your execution command.

```
-DpropertiesImplementation=org.apache.flume.node.EnvVarResolverProperties
```

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'll have to try a custom sink. Though I'm actually okay with original file name as a prefix (followed by timestamp) so I tried the ${file} prefix and I tried using the EnvVarResolverProperties execution command too but still that doesn't work. Does that mean the ${file} variable is unable to get the original file name from file header?

Comment: You are right @nonnon you'll have to try custom sink. I give the info for different scenarios. ${file} variable is not able to get original filename from header. But If you define a environment variable in your **flume-env.sh** as `file = anything` you can use the value of file in your configuration file with EnvVarResolverProperties.